# Creating a Java program that locks a file

Tags: java

How do I lock a file so that a user can only unlock it using my Java program?

```
import java.nio.channels.*;
import java.io.*;

public class filelock {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    FileLock lock = null;
    FileChannel fchannel = null;

    try {
      File file = new File("c:\\Users\\green\\Desktop\\lock.txt");

      fchannel = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw").getChannel();

      lock = fchannel.lock();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
  }
}
```

This is my sample code. It doesn't give me what I want. I want it to deny one access to read or to write the file, until I use my Java program to unlock it.

Comment: Do you want concurrency control mechanism **??**, or Security **?** Didn't get you :(

Comment: Java doesn't allow to "lock" files, as some Operating Systems don't have a file locking mechanism. If you want to do that, you'll need to use a OS specific library (and won't work on *nix, as unix doesn't have this kind of file locking)

Comment: @augusto, u said i can use os specific library, am using windows 7, so can u give me a lead on how to go about it

Comment: What actually do you mean by 'lock' a file. Your question title sounds like you just want to prevent other programs from reading and writing to the file, however from what you've said what you really want is some form of encryption so that only your program can decrypt the file and make it usable again?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Have a look. @GreenOnyeji

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do this where you want to lock:

```
File f1 = new File(Your file path);
f1.setExecutable(false);
f1.setWritable(false);
f1.setReadable(false);
```

And for unlock you can just do this:

```
File f1 = new File(Your file path);
f1.setExecutable(true);
f1.setWritable(true);
f1.setReadable(true);
```

#### Before applying

**Check if the file permission allow:**

```
file.canExecute(); – return true, file is executable; false is not.
file.canWrite(); – return true, file is writable; false is not.
file.canRead(); – return true, file is readable; false is not.
```

For a Unix system you have to put in this code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 777 file");
```

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply. but i still can read the file. What i want is something like a folder lock, denies one access to the folder once it is locked. But here am trying to do the same for file.

Comment: thanks alot, my file.canRead(); and file.canExecute(); are true, while file.canWrite(); is false. Is there any way to change all to false? mean while am gonna tick this question as answered.

Comment: You Welcome:) AnyTime :P :D

Answer (score 2):

You can lock the file by using Java code in a very simple way like:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 755 " + yourfile);
```

Here exec is a function which accepts a string value. You can put any command in that it will execute.

Or you can do it with another way like:

```
File f = new File("Your file name");
f.setExecutable(false);
f.setWritable(false);
f.setReadable(false);
```

To be sure, check the file:

```
System.out.println("Is Execute allow: " + f.canExecute());
System.out.println("Is Write allow: " + f.canWrite());
System.out.println("Is Read allow: " + f.canRead());
```